# Load data from an alias in PIG

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a query in this format

```
A = LOAD 'DB.Table_Name'  Using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() as (f1:chararray, f2:chararray,f3:chararray,f4:chararray,f5:chararray,f6:chararray,f7:chararray,f8:chararray,f9:datetime,f10:chararray) ;
B = FILTER A BY f1 == 'Colum_Name';
C = FOREACH B GENERATE CONCAT('DB_Name.',f5);
Dump C;
```

Now C have `DB.Table_name`..

Please explain **How Can I load data from the `table_name` which is in C**.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A would the following work-a-round:

```
%default TABLE_NAME `hive -e "SELECT ...your hive query to get the name from f5...;"`
C = LOAD 'DB.$TABLE_NAME' USING ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Kesco Thanks for the work around

Am trying to use it but wondering how does this work if F5 bring back multiple tables.

Comment: If you have defined number of tables, than you can use bash tools to parse the table names and store them in separate variables. After just load the tables using the defined variables.

Comment: If you have various number of tables (especially with different schemas) you can use embedded pig in e.g. python https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#embed-python